# Limbo state shutdown or reboot

Tags: boot, grub, shutdown

Computer shutdown fine, but after shutdown computer comes in to a limbo state. It it will not boot. Only showing a black screen. Holding down power button for four seconds and start computer again. Grub menu comes up. One can select Elementy OS and computer boots fine. I am using Elementaty os version 6 with updates.

Comment: You may want to check the `/var/log/syslog` file around the time of the shutdown to see what the last few messages were before the machine went into limbo. This may provide a clue about why you had to hard cycle it 

Comment: it almost sounds like it is getting into an inconsistent sleep/hibernation state such that it is trying to wake up rather than boot ... sorry but not sure how to even check for this

Answer (score 0):

That was my first go to when it occurred. Nothing out of the ordinary, what I can see. I was expecting something.